# duplicate lang item in crate `ink_env` - astar-frame/astar

Tags: ink, frame, astar, cargo

Trying to build `Astar` `shibuya-runtime` crate is failing after adding the `ink_env` dependency an `astar-frame` chain-extension.

Here are the changes to both [`Astar`](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/pull/958) and [`astar-frame`](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/astar-frame/pull/165).

**Run**: `cargo build --release -p shibuya-runtime`

**Error:**

```
  error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `ink_env` (which `nomination_pool_staking_chain_extension_types` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/snowmead/opt/projects/Astar/target/release/wbuild/shibuya-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-0c1432171814e3b5.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `ink_env` loaded from /Users/snowmead/opt/projects/Astar/target/release/wbuild/shibuya-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libink_env-71d05e5639e89bfd.rmeta
```

The `ink_env` dependency is included in the nomination-pool chain extension types crate [here](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/astar-frame/pull/165/files#diff-698c90beaf1f7500ef073ca0c4ed5f791370b74acfd75cf0c3f427b8fffd5a02R13)

Comment: do you need to add it here too? https://github.com/AstarNetwork/astar-frame/pull/165/files#diff-fba227a243c144cb57055a5cd6bc53e6eac5d1b561f93e0a8693b3dea8f5fe2bR30

Comment: No, I do not. And when I add it there, the problem isn't fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should have ink_env as a dependency of your chain extension,
If you want to use the shared `nomination-pool-staking-chain-extension-types` package, you might need to rely on optional dependencies and feature flags to only compile the `ink_env::chain_extension::FromStatusCode` trait implementation when you compile it inside your contract